# Convert hexadecimal data to text in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I know there are many questions like these, but they don't seem to work as I expect, or probably I don't know how to use them.

Basically, how can I convert this:

```
65 78 61 6d 70 6c 65
```

Into this:

```
example
```

Basically like hex editors do (HxD, Microhex, and so on)

The reason for that is because I'd like to write data based on hexadecimal data, without using

```
using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("file.txt", FileMode.Append)))
{
    bw.Write("foo bar"); // Here we are writing binary data normally, but not what I would want
}
```

Comment: What *is* this and where does it come from? Text files contain bytes too. When you use `File.ReadAllText` the bytes are converted to text using a specific codepage or encoding. You can pass the desired encoding to `File.Read...()` or `File.Write(..)` commands, StreamReader and StreamWriter

Comment: The one thing you *shouldn't* do is use `BinaryWriter`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you convert a byte array to a hexadecimal string, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)

Comment: Your source, is that a byte-array, or a string with hexadecimal pairs separated by spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have there is text which has been turned into bytes using the ASCII (or possibly UTF-8) encoding.

So, you can use a suitable `Encoding` object to turn it back. For example:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0x65, 0x78, 0x61, 0x6d, 0x70, 0x6c, 0x65 };
string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Note that you're dealing with files or streams, there are many tools which use an `Encoding` internally to convert strings to bytes or vice versa:

- `File.ReadAllText` / `File.ReadAllLines` / etc use an `Encoding` internally
- `StreamWriter` / `StreamReader` let you read/write strings to/from a stream, and turn those into bytes using an `Encoding`
- `File.OpenText` / `File.CreateText` / etc do the same thing with a file

Comment: For these who need, make sure to add "using System.Text;" if you haven't already.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to `cast byte to char`:

```
 byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0x65, 0x78, 0x61, 0x6d, 0x70, 0x6c, 0x65 };
 string result = "";
 for(int i=0;i<bytes.Length;i++)
       result+=(char)bytes[i];

 Console.WriteLine(result); //example
```

You can also use the [linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations) to convert `byte` array to `char` array. and Concate the characters using [String.Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-8.0)

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", bytes.Select(x => (char)x))); //example
```